# Usage of "deserve"

Tags: grammaticality

Does the following sentence use "deserve" correctly?

> It deserves consideration to solve the problem in the future.

By [Oxford](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/deserve), we can use "deserve something" or "deserve to do someting". Is it appropriate to use "deserve something to do something"?

Comment: OLD says: “*if somebody/something deserves something, it is right that they should have it, because of the way they have behaved or because of what they are.*” In your sentence, I think “needs or takes” are  more appropriate.

Comment: *Deserve* applies to *consideration* and it stops there; the rest of the sentence is not effected by *deserve* in any way. NARQ.

Comment: Yes but when in the future?

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you have a limited amount of resources and many problems to fix, then certain problems merit or deserve closer attention. Deserve is usually used with people as the subject, but there's no reason why it has to be. The use is perfectly common:

> v.i.
>    1. to be worthy of, qualified for, or have a claim to reward, punishment, etc.: an idea deserving of study.
>
> 2. worthy or suitable (to be given charity etc). I only give money to deserving causes.

Both these passages can be found at [Free Dictionary.](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/deserve)
Another one from Chester A. Arthur:

> The health of the people is of supreme importance. All measures
>   looking to their protection against the spread of contagious diseases
>   and to the increase of our sanitary knowledge for such purposes
>   deserve attention of Congress. Chester A. Arthur

Note in the last quote what is said to deserve attention are the measures.

Comment: I tidied up your link. Feel free to revert, if you wish.